# accessing all keys in a dictionary simultaneously

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python which looks like this:

```
mydict={
    "key1": np.array([1, 2, 3]),
    "key2": np.array([4, 5, 6]),
    "key3": np.array([7, 8, 9])
    }
```

Now, I'd like to obtain the dictionary but with just the first the nth entry in each of the value arrays. Something like `mydict2=mydict[:][1]`. The expected output would be:

```
mydict2={
    "key1": 2
    "key2": 5
    "key3": 8
    }
```

And I would like to get parts of all arrays simultaneously. For example `mydict3=mydict[:][:2]`. Here, I expect:

```
mydict3={
    "key1": np.array([1, 2]),
    "key2": np.array([4, 5]),
    "key3": np.array([7, 8])
    }
```

Obviously, indexing via [:] doesn't work.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: By *simultaneously*, you mean that you don't want to write code individually for each key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is a feature mostly offered by numpy, where slicing gives you views. Dictionaries are different beasts, partly because dictionaries are *unordered*.

You'll have to iterate in a dict comprehension:

```
mydict2 = {k: v[1] for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

and

```
mydict3 = {k: v[:2] for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

I'd simply not store numpy arrays in a dictionary, and use a larger array instead:

```
fullarray = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)
```

and, at most, use a dictionary to map keys to slices on that array. These slices give you views so altering the full array is reflected in the references in the dictionary:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> fullarray = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)
>>> mydict1 = {'key1': fullarray[0, :], 'key2': fullarray[1, :], 'key3': fullarray[2, :]}
>>> mydict1
{'key1': array([1, 2, 3]), 'key2': array([4, 5, 6]), 'key3': array([7, 8, 9])}
>>> fullarray[:, 1]
array([2, 5, 8])
>>> fullarray[:, 1] *= 2
>>> fullarray[:, 1]
array([ 4, 10, 16])
>>> mydict1
{'key1': array([1, 4, 3]), 'key2': array([ 4, 10,  6]), 'key3': array([ 7, 16,  9])}
```

but accessing a column is just simpler via the full numpy array, so `fullarray[:, 0]` and `fullarray[:, :2]`.

Another option is to use [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) to produce rows with names:

```
>>> import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn
>>> structured = rfn.unstructured_to_structured(np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3, 3)).T, names=('key1', 'key2', 'key3'))
```

at which point indexing with a key name gives you arrays:

```
>>> structured['key1']
array([1, 2, 3]
```

but you can also index by 'column', including slicing:

```
>>> structured[0]
(1, 4, 7)
>>> structured[:2]
array([(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8)],
      dtype=[('key1', '<i8'), ('key2', '<i8'), ('key3', '<i8')])
>>> structured[:2]['key1']
array([1, 2])
>>> structured[:2]['key2']
array([4, 5])
>>> structured[:2]['key3']
array([7, 8])
```

Converting an existing dictionary would require stacking the values:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

def dict_to_structured(d):
    return rfn.unstructured_to_structured(
        np.stack(list(mydict.values()), axis=1),
        names=list(mydict)
    )
```

Comment: thanks for the very pythonic-looking solution! This is exactly what I want. I am using dictionaries since that's what I get using scipy.signal.find_peaks.
And thanks once more for the great idea of adding keys to an array.

Comment: @riddleculous: you could convert the scipy result to a structured result too, I added an example function.

Comment: thanks also for the great example using structured arrays. I didn't try out conversion since at the moment I don't want to update to the latest numpy release but I will keep it in mind for the future.